# StructureMap object reload

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, structuremap

to simplify, I have an AppSettings:IAppSettings class which is initialized at start of the application:

```
ObjectFactory.Initialize(x =>
{
    x.Scan(scan => {
        scan.TheCallingAssembly();

        scan.WithDefaultConventions();
    });
    x.AddRegistry<DataAccessRegistry>();
    x.AddRegistry<AuthorizationRegistry>();

    x.For<IAppSettings>()
        .Use<AppSettings>()
        .Ctor<Dictionary<string, string>>()
            .Is(ctx =>
            {
                Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                var sessionFactory = ctx.GetInstance<ISessionFactory>();
                using (var session = sessionFactory.OpenSession())
                using (var tx = session.BeginTransaction())
                {
                    // query the SETTINGS table
                    foreach (Setting _setting in session.QueryOver<Setting>().List())
                    {
                        dict[_setting.Key] = _setting.Value;
                    }
                    tx.Commit();
                }
                return dict;
            });

    x.UseDefaultStructureMapConfigFile = false;
});
```

So, when creating a class that requires settings, I simply use the following

```
public class AccessDataService {
    private IAppSettings settings;

    public AccessDataService(IAppSettings p_appSettings) {
        settings = p_appSettings;
    }
....
}
```

and structuremap nicely injects the object into my instance of a class.

However, I would like to be able to trigger database setting reload explicitly so I was wondering if there is a way to tell structuremap to purge all existing objects of AppSettings and recreate them, loading the settings from the DB again?

Cheers

Comment: By your configuration, it should reload every time a new `AppSettings` object is created. By StructureMap's default, it should be per request. Any IoC container I've used allowed to create a custom lifetime manager. This page is missing with a "Forthcoming..." message in StructureMap's doc. So I'm not sure if this is just missing from the docs or not yet implemented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use EjectAllInstancesOf method every time you need to refresh :

```
ObjectFactory.EjectAllInstancesOf<IAppSettings>();
ObjectFactory.Inject<IAppSettings>(*your new object*);
```